# ORACLE: How to check for and remove repeating column values

Tags: sql, oracle

For the "B numbers" - (the number to which a call was made), please limit each occurrence to 3. That is, from the list of "A numbers"-(the number that made the call to the "B number"), we may have multiple persons calling the same "B number". In instances where the "B number" appears more than 3 times in the total dial list, please remove them from the subsequent "A numbers" that they may show up for.

I want to figure out how can i check for and remove these repeating "B numbers" when they are greater than 3 occurrences.

Here is a sample list the table structure.

[image]

So where the B number occurs more than three time i want to keep the A number but remove the B number. Any Thought?

Comment: School work? What have you tried? How did it go?

Comment: And what is the logic behind which records are removed?

Comment: you want to remove only the "B" Number or some rows?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the description the logic is if a B number occurs more than three times then it should not be included in the result list. ie. if 5 persons called the same B number then only 3 of the 5 A numbers get to keep a matching record with that B  number.

Comment: @Aツ I only want to remove just the B number not the entire record

Comment: and why do you want to do that? is that just for display or do you really want to transform your data into junk?

Comment: I have been braining storming for a couple days now....I am not sure how to achieve this using SQL seeing the nature of the language, seems to only be solvable from a programming perspective. Not very experienced with writing queries of this nature.

Comment: @Aツ come to think of it, Yes, it would be the entire record

Comment: @Aツ seeing that there will be no matching B number for that A number once the number of occurrences for the B number is greater than 3, yes, we would remove the record. that is the goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limiting your results to 3 `B Number`s at most is easy using the `row_number()` analytic function.

```
select a_number, b_number
  from (select a_number, b_number,
               row_number() over (partition by b_number order by null) as rn
          from your_table)
 where rn <= 3
```

However, the above query is not explicit about ***which*** 3 rows it will preserve (`order by null`).

If you want to keep the first 3 occurrences of a `B Number` in your list, then you need a way to explicitly define the order of your list.  Do you have some timestamp field perhaps?

In any case, whatever field(s) define(s) the order of your list, use that in the `order by` clause of the `row_number()` function call:

```
row_number() over (partition by b_number order by pick_an_ordering_column)
```

Comment: Ok. The order does not matter. Just any first three occurrences of the b number

Comment: Gonna order by the A number